# BoxConstraints forces an infinite height: SizedBox.Expand()

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview, flutter-gridview

Im building a List View for displaying videos.I'm using ListView to display 2 videos beside each other for each blog post.
I've wrapped ListView inside a SizedBox of a custom height and width. For the first 2 blog posts the 2 videos display correctly, but when I scroll below to the third blog post one I get :

> BoxConstraints forces an infinite height: The relevant error causing widget was
> SizedBox.Expand().

The Page rendering the blog posts itself freezes with an out of memory error and crashes. I have to run debug all over again.

Here is my code :

```html
Widget _buildVideoPlayerListTwo(
      {List<PostMedia>? mediaItems,
      double? width,
      double? height,
      Post? post}) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: widget.height,
      width: widget.width,
      child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          physics: const PageScrollPhysics(),
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: mediaItems!.length,
          itemExtent: 186,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 2, right: 2),
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(6),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(6),
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(6),
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(6)),
                    child: SizedBox.expand(
                      child: FittedBox(
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height: widget.height,
                          width: widget.width,
                          child: KNVideoPlayer(
                            videoUrl:
                                mediaItems[index].contentObject.file.toString(),
                            thumbnailUrl: mediaItems[index]
                                .contentObject
                                .thumbnail
                                .toString(),
                            isConstrained: widget.isConstrained,
                            controller: _knVideoPlayerController,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            );
          }),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can't let the `SizedBox` expand while it's inside a scroll view.

The parent SizedBox constraints:

```
return SizedBox(
  height: widget.height,
  width: widget.width,
  child: ListView.builder(
```

while the leaf of your tree `videoPlayer` contraints:

```
 child: SizedBox(
                          height: widget.height,
                          width: widget.width,
                          child: KNVideoPlayer(
```

in all cases the video allocate the whole screen, **what is the purpose of expanded sized box ?**

i think your problem is to make the video covers the screen, not to be contained!

if so, try to remove Expnded SizedBox and wrap your video player with that fitted box:

```
 child: SizedBox
                 height: widget.height,
                 width: widget.width,
                          child: FittedBox -----> cover--> KNVideoPlayer(
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. While I did the above. While the 2 videos appear beside each other without any errors, the controls indie the video like expand to full screen, Play/Pause are hidden. Thankfully I have a play button in the center to play and pause but the overall, doesnt do good. The bottom video time bar appears cut from both side

Comment: I partially achieved displaying all the video player controls by doing a Boxfit.fill, however with a ListView of height 350 where the height is high , I couldn't figure to make the controls looks normal , not stretched. Also the fill makes the video player not occupy the Sized box. Can we continue this dicsussion over chat ?